# What causes this high variability in cycles for a simple tight loop with -O0 but not -O3, on a Cortex-A72?

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, performancecounter

I'm running some experiments around getting highly consistent runtimes for a piece of code. The code I'm currently timing is a pretty arbitrary CPU-bound workload:

```c
int cpu_workload_external_O3(){
    int x = 0;
    for(int ind = 0; ind < 12349560; ind++){
        x = ((x ^ 0x123) + x * 3) % 123456;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I've written a kernel module that disables interrupts and then runs 10 trials of the above function, timing each trial by taking the difference in the clock cycle counter from before and after. Other things to note:

- the machine is an ARM Cortex-A72, with 4 sockets with 4 cores each (each with its own L1 cache)
- clock frequency scaling is off
- hyperthreading is not supported
- the machine is running virtually nothing except for some bare-bones system processes

In other words, I believe most/all sources of system variability are accounted for, and, especially when run as a kernel module with interrupts disabled via `spin_lock_irqsave()`, the code should achieve pretty much identical performance run-to-run (maybe a small performance hit on the first run when some instruction is first pulled into cache, but that's it).

Indeed, when the benchmarked code is compiled with `-O3`, I saw a range of at most 200 cycles out of ~135,845,192 on average, with most of the trials taking exactly the same amount of time. *However*, when compiled with `-O0`, the range shot up to as much as 158,386 cycles out of ~262,710,916. By range I mean the difference between the longest and shortest running times. Moreover, for the `-O0` code, there's not much consistency to which of the trials is the slowest/fastest -- counterintuitively, in one occasion the fastest was the very first, and the slowest was the one right after!

**So**: what might be causing this high upper bound on variability in the `-O0` code? Looking at the assembly, it seems that the `-O3` code stores everything (?) in a register, whereas the `-O0` code has a bunch of references to `sp` and so it seems to be accessing memory. But even then, I'd expect everything to get brought into L1 cache and sit there with a pretty deterministic access time.

---

## Code

The code being benchmarked is in the snippet above. The assembly is below. Both were compiled with `gcc 7.4.0` with no flags except for `-O0` and `-O3`.

#### `-O0`

```
0000000000000000 <cpu_workload_external_O0>:
   0:   d10043ff        sub     sp, sp, #0x10
   4:   b9000bff        str     wzr, [sp, #8]
   8:   b9000fff        str     wzr, [sp, #12]
   c:   14000018        b       6c <cpu_workload_external_O0+0x6c>
  10:   b9400be1        ldr     w1, [sp, #8]
  14:   52802460        mov     w0, #0x123                      // #291
  18:   4a000022        eor     w2, w1, w0
  1c:   b9400be1        ldr     w1, [sp, #8]
  20:   2a0103e0        mov     w0, w1
  24:   531f7800        lsl     w0, w0, #1
  28:   0b010000        add     w0, w0, w1
  2c:   0b000040        add     w0, w2, w0
  30:   528aea61        mov     w1, #0x5753                     // #22355
  34:   72a10fc1        movk    w1, #0x87e, lsl #16
  38:   9b217c01        smull   x1, w0, w1
  3c:   d360fc21        lsr     x1, x1, #32
  40:   130c7c22        asr     w2, w1, #12
  44:   131f7c01        asr     w1, w0, #31
  48:   4b010042        sub     w2, w2, w1
  4c:   529c4801        mov     w1, #0xe240                     // #57920
  50:   72a00021        movk    w1, #0x1, lsl #16
  54:   1b017c41        mul     w1, w2, w1
  58:   4b010000        sub     w0, w0, w1
  5c:   b9000be0        str     w0, [sp, #8]
  60:   b9400fe0        ldr     w0, [sp, #12]
  64:   11000400        add     w0, w0, #0x1
  68:   b9000fe0        str     w0, [sp, #12]
  6c:   b9400fe1        ldr     w1, [sp, #12]
  70:   528e0ee0        mov     w0, #0x7077                     // #28791
  74:   72a01780        movk    w0, #0xbc, lsl #16
  78:   6b00003f        cmp     w1, w0
  7c:   54fffcad        b.le    10 <cpu_workload_external_O0+0x10>
  80:   b9400be0        ldr     w0, [sp, #8]
  84:   910043ff        add     sp, sp, #0x10
  88:   d65f03c0        ret
```

#### `-O3`

```
0000000000000000 <cpu_workload_external_O3>:
   0:   528e0f02        mov     w2, #0x7078                     // #28792
   4:   5292baa4        mov     w4, #0x95d5                     // #38357
   8:   529c4803        mov     w3, #0xe240                     // #57920
   c:   72a01782        movk    w2, #0xbc, lsl #16
  10:   52800000        mov     w0, #0x0                        // #0
  14:   52802465        mov     w5, #0x123                      // #291
  18:   72a043e4        movk    w4, #0x21f, lsl #16
  1c:   72a00023        movk    w3, #0x1, lsl #16
  20:   4a050001        eor     w1, w0, w5
  24:   0b000400        add     w0, w0, w0, lsl #1
  28:   0b000021        add     w1, w1, w0
  2c:   71000442        subs    w2, w2, #0x1
  30:   53067c20        lsr     w0, w1, #6
  34:   9ba47c00        umull   x0, w0, w4
  38:   d364fc00        lsr     x0, x0, #36
  3c:   1b038400        msub    w0, w0, w3, w1
  40:   54ffff01        b.ne    20 <cpu_workload_external_O3+0x20>  // b.any
  44:   d65f03c0        ret
```

#### kernel module

The code running the trials is below. It reads `PMCCNTR_EL0` before/after each iteration, stores the differences in an array, and prints out the min/max times in the end across all trials. The functions `cpu_workload_external_O0` and `cpu_workload_external_O3` are in external object files that are compiled separately, and then linked in.

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

#include "cpu.h"

static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(lock);

void runBenchmark(int (*benchmarkFunc)(void)){
    // Enable perf counters.
    u32 pmcr;
    asm volatile("mrs %0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (pmcr));
    asm volatile("msr pmcr_el0, %0" : : "r" (pmcr|(1)));

    // Run trials, storing the time of each in `clockDiffs`.
    u32 result = 0;
    #define numtrials 10
    u32 clockDiffs[numtrials] = {0};
    u32 clockStart, clockEnd;
    for(int trial = 0; trial < numtrials; trial++){
        asm volatile("isb; mrs %0, PMCCNTR_EL0" : "=r" (clockStart));
        result += benchmarkFunc();
        asm volatile("isb; mrs %0, PMCCNTR_EL0" : "=r" (clockEnd));

        // Reset PMCCNTR_EL0.
        asm volatile("mrs %0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (pmcr));
        asm volatile("msr pmcr_el0, %0" : : "r" (pmcr|(((uint32_t)1) << 2)));

        clockDiffs[trial] = clockEnd - clockStart;
    }

    // Compute the min and max times across all trials.
    u32 minTime = clockDiffs[0];
    u32 maxTime = clockDiffs[0];
    for(int ind = 1; ind < numtrials; ind++){
        u32 time = clockDiffs[ind];
        if(time < minTime){
            minTime = time;
        } else if(time > maxTime){
            maxTime = time;
        }
    }

    // Print the result so the benchmark function doesn't get optimized out.
    printk("result: %d\n", result);

    printk("diff: max %d - min %d = %d cycles\n", maxTime, minTime, maxTime - minTime);
}

int init_module(void) {
    printk("enter\n");
    unsigned long flags;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);

    printk("-O0\n");
    runBenchmark(cpu_workload_external_O0);

    printk("-O3\n");
    runBenchmark(cpu_workload_external_O3);

    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
    printk("exit\n");
}
```

---

## Hardware

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        aarch64
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           4
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               3
Model name:          Cortex-A72
Stepping:            r0p3
BogoMIPS:            166.66
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           48K
L2 cache:            2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15
Flags:               fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid
```

```
$ lscpu --extended
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2 ONLINE
0   0    0      0    0:0:0      yes
1   0    0      1    1:1:0      yes
2   0    0      2    2:2:0      yes
3   0    0      3    3:3:0      yes
4   0    1      4    4:4:1      yes
5   0    1      5    5:5:1      yes
6   0    1      6    6:6:1      yes
7   0    1      7    7:7:1      yes
8   0    2      8    8:8:2      yes
9   0    2      9    9:9:2      yes
10  0    2      10   10:10:2    yes
11  0    2      11   11:11:2    yes
12  0    3      12   12:12:3    yes
13  0    3      13   13:13:3    yes
14  0    3      14   14:14:3    yes
15  0    3      15   15:15:3    yes
```

```
$ numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
node 0 size: 32159 MB
node 0 free: 30661 MB
node distances:
node   0
  0:  10
```

---

## Sample Measurements

Below is some output from one execution of the kernel module:

```
[902574.112692] kernel-module: running on cpu 15                                                                                                                                      
[902576.403537] kernel-module: trial 00: 309983568 74097394 98796602 <-- max
[902576.403539] kernel-module: trial 01: 309983562 74097397 98796597                                                                                                                  
[902576.403540] kernel-module: trial 02: 309983562 74097397 98796597                                                                                                                  
[902576.403541] kernel-module: trial 03: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403543] kernel-module: trial 04: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403544] kernel-module: trial 05: 309983562 74097397 98796597                                                                                                                  
[902576.403545] kernel-module: trial 06: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403547] kernel-module: trial 07: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403548] kernel-module: trial 08: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403550] kernel-module: trial 09: 309983562 74097397 98796597                                                                                                                  
[902576.403551] kernel-module: trial 10: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403552] kernel-module: trial 11: 309983562 74097397 98796597
[902576.403554] kernel-module: trial 12: 309983562 74097397 98796597                                                                                                                  
[902576.403555] kernel-module: trial 13: 309849076 74097403 98796630 <-- min
[902576.403557] kernel-module: trial 14: 309983562 74097397 98796597                                                                                                                  
[902576.403558] kernel-module: min time: 309849076
[902576.403559] kernel-module: max time: 309983568                                                                                                                                    
[902576.403560] kernel-module: diff: 134492
```

For each trial, the values reported are: # of cycles (0x11), # of L1D accesses (0x04), # of L1I accesses (0x14). I'm using section 11.8 of [this ARM PMU reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100095_0003_06_en/index.html)).

Comment: Are there other threads running? Their memory accesses causing competition for bus bandwidth and cache space could be having an effect.

Comment: Could be. I haven't isolcpu'd any cores, and even then a kernel thread might get scheduled on one of the other cores on the socket. But if I'm understanding `lscpu --extended` correctly, then each core has its own L1 data and instruction caches, and then each socket has a shared L2 cache for its 4 cores, so as long as everything's done within L1 cache I would expect the code to pretty much "own" its bus (as it's the only thing running on its core, until completion). I don't know much about hardware at this level, though.

Comment: You have a quad-*socket* system with four separate physical silicon chips, each being a quad-core A72?  With some googling, I found some high-end ARM servers with dual sockets, so apparently dual-socket ARM does exist at least.  But with only 4 cores per package?  Is that for more NUMA mem bandwidth?  Anyway, what hardware are you running on?  I assume this is code stays hot in L1i cache so bus contention for I-fetch shouldn't matter, and the only memory access is the stack (so should also stay in L1d cache).  So we shouldn't be seeing any weird NUMA effects on your HW, right?

Comment: Anyway yes, your `-O3` code is purely registers, no loads or stores in the disassembled function.  And yes, the `-O0` code spills everything to the stack between every C statement.  See [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) for why it does that.  If store-to-load forwarding latency (from the store buffer, bypassing commit to L1d cache) can vary with anything, that would explain perf variability.  That is the case on x86 Sandybridge-family, e.g. an extra store can speed up a `-O0` loop

Comment: Why don't you use a hardware profiler? ARM has lots of profiling counters for all kinds of events for L1D, L2D, Bus, Mem accesses, etc. Even when everything fits in L1D, the data still needs to be written to RAM at some point.

Comment: @rustyx: Most modern ARM CPUs have write-*back* L1d caches.  Yes "everything" needs to get written back to DRAM eventually, but that's once, at the end of the loop, some time after it stops being "hot" and the only cache line accessed at all.  And it's 1 or at most 2 cache lines, for 2 `int` locals. (`x` and the loop counter).  But yes, use perf counters to verify there are no L1d misses, and no off-core memory traffic.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I've appended some hardware info to the post. Could be that lscpu is misreporting something, but based on that and `lstopo` it seems like 4 sockets x 4 cores to me. I had the same thinking w.r.t. L1 cache, that everything should sit there and that the access time shouldn't jitter.

Comment: @rustyx, I cycled through pretty much all the perf counters but didn't see anything interesting. Number of L1I and L1D cache is the same across trials, with no L2 accesses for either -O0 or -O3 (except for 1 or 2 at the very beginning). The -O0 has lots of L1D accesses whereas the -O3 has virtually none.

Comment: Yeah, it's clearly reported as 4 sockets, but that might just be a matter of how the interconnect is wired up inside a 16-core SoC.  But you have the physical machine, right?  Do you have a brand and model number for it?  If the lid comes off, presumably you can also confirm whether there are really 4 separate sockets.  I don't see why any of this would matter, though, except for maybe the vendor / model number of the mobo.  Your benchmark is purely single core and should stay hot in cache, so all that should matter is the A72 core itself and its store buffer + store forwarding.

Comment: I changed up the kernel module to track three counters and added some sample output. What's interesting is that most of the runs are consistent, but then a random one will be substantially faster. In this case, it looks like the fastest one actually had very slightly *more* L1 accesses, which maybe implies a more aggressive branch prediction somewhere.

Also, unfortunately I don't have access to the machine. It's an AWS a1.metal instance (which gives you full ownership of the physical hardware, so there's ostensibly no interference from a hypervisor etc.).

Comment: I suppose if you consider the fact that there are 75m data accesses and a variability of at most 200,000 cycles, that roughly means that one of 375 accesses took just a cycle longer than on average. Maybe that's reasonable on its own, but why would they all happen all of a sudden in some random trial, whereas all the others are consistent?

Comment: FWIW, I re-ran a comprehensive experiment in which I collected all of the available performance counters and compared them against the fluctuations in cycles. I did this one counter at a time, to avoid any noise from working with a few dozen counters simultaneously. The only ones that are remotely correlated are `L1D_CACHE_WB_CLEAN` and `L1D_CACHE_INVAL`, but not perfectly, and the correlation is actually negative (i.e. cycles decrease when these values increase). But these counters are 0 for most runs. I bet these are only a symptom of the real root cause, though.

Comment: Interestingly, if I make the kernel module run this code on all CPUs simultaneously via `on_each_cpu()`, each one reports almost no variability at all across 100 trials.

Comment: (you forgot to @notify me, I only noticed your replies when looking at the bounty).  *it looks like the fastest one actually had very slightly more L1 accesses* Higher absolute total for the same # of loop iterations, not just per time because it was running faster?  You'd only get more L1 accesses because of branch prediction if it was *mis*-predicting and doing loads on the wrong path, then having to recover and run the correct path.  No existing CPUs speculate down both sides of a branch simultaneously even when they don't have a good prediction.  (But your branch should predict perfectly.)

Comment: Possibly DMA on another core could be invalidating caches?  Seems highly unlikely, cache invalidation should only affect certain lines.  Something I think I've occasionally seen on x86 is a loop with bi-modal performance; there are semi-stable "slow" and "fast" states for how out-of-order instruction scheduling happens.  But I've never really figured out what the details of each of the states were.  Sometimes returning from an interrupt can get it out of a slow state when execution of the loop resumes.  But you say this runs consistently inside a kernel module so that's prob. not it.

Comment: At some point I normally just give up in a case like this where the variation is a very small fraction of the overall runtime.  If we were actually optimizing, we'd just remove the store/reload bottlenecks created by `-O0` codegen and that would solve it.  It's possible that there's something interesting to learn about how A72 cores handle store/reload bottlenecked workloads so good question, but in the big picture bottlenecks like this are often easy to avoid.  (Pass args by value in registers, compile with optimization.)

Answer (score 4):

In recent Linux kernels the automatic NUMA page migration mechanism periodically shoots down TLB entries so that it can monitor NUMA locality.  TLB reloads will slow down the O0 code, even if the data remains in the L1DCache.

The page migration mechanism should not be activated on kernel pages.

You check to see if automatic NUMA page migration is enabled with

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/numa_balancing
```

and you can disable it with

```
$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/numa_balancing
```

Comment: I've been doing some related testing lately. I'm running a workload that makes a bunch of random accesses to a buffer of memory that fits comfortably in L1 cache. I run a bunch of trials back to back, and the running time is highly consistent (varies literally less than 0.001%), except periodically there is a small upwards spike. In that spike the benchmark runs just 0.014% longer. This is small, but each of these spikes has exactly the same magnitude, and a spike occurs once almost exactly once every 2 seconds. This machine has `numa_balancing` disabled. Perhaps you have an idea?

Comment: Figured it out. I was staring at perf counters all day but turns out the root cause was something totally unrelated.. I was running these tests in a tmux session on a quiet machine. The 2 second interval coincided exactly with the refresh interval of my tmux statusline, which makes a network request among some other things.. Disabling it made the spikes disappear. No idea how the scripts run by my status line on a different core cluster was impacting the process running on an isolated core cluster, touching only L1 data..

Answer (score 2):

Your variance is in the order of 6*10^-4.  While shockingly more than 1.3*10^-6, once your program is talking to the caches, it is involved in many synchronized operations.   Synchronized always means wasted time.

An interesting thing is how your -O0, -O3 comparison mimiks the general rule that an L1-cache-hit is about 2x a register reference.  Your average O3 runs in 51.70% of the time your O0 does.  When you apply the lower/uppper variances, we have (O3-200)/(O0+158386), we see a an improvement to 51.67%.

In short, yes, a cache will never be deterministic; and the low variance you see is in line with what should be expected from synchronizing with a slower device.  It is only a large variance when compared to the more deterministic register-only machine.

Comment: Instructions get fetched from L1i cache.  I guess you're saying *that* can't suffer from unpredictable slowdowns because it's not coherent with data caches on the same or other cores?  But anyway, if Dr. Bandwidth's answer is right, the variance isn't due to cache itself, but rather to periodic dTLB invalidation by the kernel.  That explanation fully explains all the observation: the increased variance from including any loads/stores in user-space, and the fact that this drop doesn't happen when timing the loop inside a kernel module.  (Linux kernel memory isn't swappable.)

Comment: Caches typically are deterministic when you're accessing hot data.  They can be multi-ported to allow coherency traffic without disturbing loads/stores from the core itself.  Your guess that disturbances are due to other cores is *plausible* but I the `numa_balancing` TLB invalidations alone probably explain it.

Comment: Any snooping cache has to have an uninterruptible sequence wherein any request must be stalled.  A slowdown of 10^-4 on a 1 vs 2 cycle operation means a one clock hiccough every 10^5 operations.  The whole question is really a no-op, the variance is tiny.